# Hide and show element based on value Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have some variable that is a boolean and can be true or false, based on that value I have to show some element in HTML like this:

```html
<p *ngif=isOwner>Test</p>
```

The problem is I have that I have to hide that element is value is false but to show element is value is true:

```js
this.storage.get('User').then((val) => {
    this.isOwner = val.Owner.IsOwner;
});
```

What will be the proper way to do that in Angular 2, just within HTML, value will always be there, and will be true or false?

Comment: `<p *ngIf="isOwner">Test</p>`

Comment: isOwner can be TRUE or FALSE, it will exist

Comment: this kind of question should not be asked here. Angular doc needs just to be red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just inverse the boolean value of the condition:

[See live stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdeozg)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public isOwner: boolean = true;
  toggleIsOwner() {
    this.isOwner = !this.isOwner; 
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="toggleIsOwner()">show/hide</button>

<p *ngIf="isOwner">Hello World!</p>
```

`showMe` is a boolean. The way [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) works is that when the expression is true, the element is inserted in the DOM, when the expression is false, the element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: No i get that value from storage dont have toggle button,

Comment: I have to show that element is value is true, and hide if value is false, not toggling that

Comment: @MiomirDancevic, you don't need the toggle function, it will work simply based on the value of the boolean.

Comment: It does not work, it hide even if value is true even if value is false

Comment: No, you are incorrect, show your actual LIVE code if you need help. You can use stackblitz.com